# WordPress : Simple php IF statement not processing

Tags: php, wordpress

can someone explain why the else statement is not working in WordPress for the sidebar.php?

```
<?php if(is_front_page() ) : ?>

 **content shows on main page sidebar**

<?php elseif(!is_front_page() ) : ?>
<?php // else: ?> // tried **else:** also

 **some content**
 **nothing is shown on any other page...**

<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: This is strange, this code should work: <?php if(is_front_page() || is_home()) { echo 'welcome home!'; } else { echo 'you are not home!'; } ?>

Comment: What is happening that leads you to believe it is not working?

Comment: @MrSlayer the content for the Front page is shown. but the else statement which should show content on all other pages is not processing. I stripped everything and just put Test Front and Test Others ... Test Others never appeared on any of the other pages

Comment: Have you tried the code using one of the default themes?  I'm thinking there may be a call to `query_posts` in the theme or functions, without properly calling `wp_reset_query()` afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

The `is_front_page()` conditional will always return false if it is used inside the loop or after the loop has ran (like in a sidebar).  You can call wp_reset_query(); after your loop to reset the page query_vars.

See [this answer on WPSE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/53444/251) for more info.

Answer (score -1):

Im not sure if is_front_page() exists, but just use {} around each condition result:

```
<?php if(is_front_page() ) { ?>

 **content shows on main page sidebar**

<?php } else { ?>
 // tried **else:** also

 **some content**
 **nothing is shown on any other page...**

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: according to WP is does http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#The_Front_Page ... is there a setting or feature that would turn off sidebar.php on all Pages or than the main? something is stopping the loading of the sidebar content on other pages.

Comment: This doesn't really do anything differently. PHP lets you use the `if(): else: endif;` syntax or `if(){}else(){}` and they are functionally equivalent.